# How to modify view in powerbi based on current time?

Tags: powerbi, dax

How do I modify my grid visual based on current time? My data has historical values of a particular parameter and corresponding hour value. I want to display top 10 rows based on that parameter for current hour. Please help.

Comment: Please have a  look at this: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

In Power BI, you'll find a filters pane on the right side of the screen. Once you select your grid visual, the hour value should be populated in that. You can give **advanced filtering** to that field and filter Top N values